# Function for coefficients matrix in constraints

Tags: visual-c++, cplex

I need coefficients matrix in constraints. There is a function getObjCoef for objective coefficient in CPLEX concert C++ but i don't know is there any function to retrieve coefficients matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to iterate on coefficients with IloExpr::LinearIterator

```
IloExpr exprCt = rangeCt.getExpr(); 

for (IloExpr::LinearIterator t = exprCt.getLinearIterator(); t.ok(); ++t) 
{ std::cout << t.getCoef() << " * " << t.getVar() << std::endl; }
```